# ORDER BY % which is calculated inside original while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I want to order results based on an maths sum answer within the main results query, heres what I mean:

My current code looks something like this:

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE foobar='{$fobo}' ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query);

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {

   $percent = round((100 * $row['wins'] / ($row['wins'] + $row['loses'])));

     echo 'blah blah blah' . $percent;

}
```

As you can see I currently ORDER BY id:

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE foobar='{$fobo}' ORDER BY id DESC";
```

but I want to ORDER BY the `$percent` answer but thats calculated inside the while loop.

I tried creating a query and putting it before the main results query:

```
$p  = "SELECT wins, loses FROM foo WHERE foobar='{$fobo}'";
$pr = mysql_query($p);

$pow = mysql_fetch_array($pr);
$percent = round((100 * $pow['wins'] / ($pow['wins'] + $pow['loses'])));
```

but that spat out

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean

I think the % calculation can be done within the main query rather than a php sum which I think would do it but I don't know what that query is.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). See the [**red box**](http://php.net/mysql-connect)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, try [this article](http://php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing). If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 5):

Instead of computing `percentage` value inside loop and then sorting using another loop, you can do it in just one query as:

```
$query  = "SELECT foo.*,
                  ROUND((100 * wins / (wins + loses))) AS percentage
           FROM foo
           WHERE foobar='{$fobo}'
           ORDER BY percentage ASC";

$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   echo 'blah blah blah' . $row['percentage'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a column number like this:

```
select
    col1,
    col2
    round((100*wins)/wins+loses)
from
    foo
where
    foobar='{$fobo}'
group by
    col1,
    col2
order by
    3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can perform calculation in your order by clause

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
ORDER BY ROUND((100*wins) / (wins+loses)) DESC
```